# Рандомное число с максимально заданным числом

Tags: android, случайные-числа

Всем привет, помогите пожалуйста, как сделать прогу, чтобы получить рандомное число с максимально заданным значением, с использованием EditText (здесь максимальное значение рандома), TextView (здесь полученное значение) и Button

Comment: Вы пробовали что то сделать самостоятельно, приложите код ваших попыток, опишите, что именно у вас не получается и как вы пробовали это решить. Или вы просто выдаете задание на то, что вам нужно, но как делать вы представления не имеете? Дело в том, что здесь обычно не пишут проги по заказу, а помогают написать прогу тем, кто сам хочет, но что то не получается

Comment: Извините, не так выразился, не программу, а просто код. Я сам только начал изучать Android Studio и не совсем понимаю все используемые коды. Естественно я сам пробовал, используя данные которые я мог найти в инете, но получалась какая-то белеберда.

Comment: Как здесь [задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы получить полезный ответ и мое мнение, [как чему то реально научиться](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=159318&view=findpost&p=64085581) в android-разработке. PS: изучать вы взялись, видимо, фреймворк Android, а не программу для написания кода (Android Studio)

Answer (score 2):

```
TextView tv = ...;
EditText et = ...;

TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(final CharSequence charSequence, final int i, final int i1, final int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence charSequence, final int i, final int i1, final int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(final Editable editable) {
        try {
            int max = Integer.parseInt(editable);
            int random = new Random().nextInt(max);
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(random))
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

et.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```